# Can I suppress or enforce URLs to be prefaced with http:// in ALL browsers?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to ensure that regardless of what browser a user is in, they all see the EXACT same characters in the URL bar.

Most browsers show the preceding protocol type in the URL bar. However, Chrome for example truncates http:// (not sure about https) and starts with the domain name, ie:

**Chrome:** *stackoverflow.com/questions/ask*
**Safari:** *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask*

So, is there a way to either suppress the http:// in all browsers, or even enforce it in all browsers? Preferably suppress.

Comment: Just a side note - if you copy-paste a URL from Chrome, it will paste with the http:// prefix even though it isn't visible in the address bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, is there a way to either suppress the http:// in all browsers, or even enforce it in all browsers? Preferably suppress.

Not that I know of, no. How the URL is displayed in the address bar is totally up to each browser.

However, using `https://` seems to trigger the prefix being shown in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari (tested on Windows 7). If your requirement is really, really important, you could consider switching to that.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't - and thats a positive thing.

That would mean that you would be able to change some configuration settings on the current client which would be a great security threat. Imagine that any site you could visit could change how your browser should work?